# Question about set order theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory, recursion

Suppose we have an ordered set $(A,\le)$ with the property that, for any decreasing chain (sequence) $a_0 \ge a_1 \ge \dotsb$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $a_n=a_{n+k}$.

We have to prove that any non empty subset $B \subseteq A$ has a minimal element.

I'm new to order theory, so I can not figure out how to deal with this problem.

Comment: What has your question to do with `linear-algebra`, `abstract-algebra`, or `multisets`?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, sorry for that, fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Axiom of Choice, and in particular, its equivalent *Zorn's Lemma*, combined with the *Recursion Theorem*.

Assume that $B\ne \varnothing$ does not possess a minimal element. Picking an $a_0\in B$ you can define recursively the sequence
$$
\text{$a_n$ is an element of $B$ strictly smaller than $a_{n-1}$}.
$$
Such $a_n$ exists in $B$, since $a_{n-1}$ is, by assumption, not a minimal element, 
and this leads to a contradiction.

Comment: This is not really a proof by contradiction, but rather by contrapositive.